# No error message when comment is too short on mobile version

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

When I try to submit too short comment on a full version of the site, I get a message

> X more to go...

When I do the same on a mobile version of the site, nothing happens. The comment is not submitted and I get no feedback.

Tested on Safari iOS 8.4 iPhone 5.

Comment: Same behavior on Moto X with android 4.4.4 using Chrome.  I hit the add comment button and nothing happens.